# Timer class not working

Tags: java, debugging, timer

I learning about the Timer class

```
package testing;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Testing extends JPanel 
{



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                // Output function
                System.out.println("HowareYou"); // function to be run after 5 seconds

            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false); // Only execute once
        timer.start(); // Go go go!

    }


}
```

Why doesnt the output function execute 5 seconds after the start of the program , instead it never executes ???

Comment: You need a frame for the program.

Comment: Not really, but of course extending JPanel would suggest that he wants some graphical elements there (eventually).

Comment: For Swing Timer, yes you would need one.

Comment: Alright, I wasn't paying attention on whether it was a java.util.Timer or a swing timer.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `Thread.sleep(10000);` at the end of your program.  I think the program is exiting before the timer can fire......

Comment: Preferably `Thread.sleep(10000);` if he has a 5 second delay on the timer.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't exit from my own sleep method long enough ago, evidently.  Correction made.

Answer (score 1):

A Swing Timer requires a Swing application to activate the timer. Move the timer code itself into an instance method of the class and add [it to a JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your program is

The program ends (JVM exits) soon after timer.start(); so your timer is not given a chance to run.
You can pause the main thread with Thread.sleep(5000); soon after starting the timer to give it a chance to run before main exits.

- `javax.swing.Timer` class can only be used in Swing applications.
- `javax.swing.Timer` is not as powerful as `java.util.Timer`
- `javax.swing.Timer` is a more appropriate choice over java.util.Timer for Swing applications because `javax.swing.Timer handles thread sharing`
- You need to implement the java.awt.event.ActionListener interface and write your task code in its actionPerformed method

Its better to use `java.util.Timer` has more features see [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=160)